Splitting shapefiles based on ID: error "could not create layer"
I am trying to split a shapefile in different shapefiles based on ID attributes in QGIS 3.28.
I used Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer, chose a directory I had previously created, and after a few cycles this kind of error appears in Log:

Could not create layer
/private/var/folders/v3/44wyp6l959zdv0vsnzdn1mmh0000gn/T/processing_GQuoNg/47e5aecc8ed1451099ef74574d6e3cae/OUTPUT/COD_HABITA_7220*/9180*.shp:
Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file
/private/var/folders/v3/44wyp6l959zdv0vsnzdn1mmh0000gn/T/processing_GQuoNg/47e5aecc8ed1451099ef74574d6e3cae/OUTPUT/COD_HABITA_7220*/9180*.shp:
No such file or directory) Execution failed after 0.15 seconds

The software is able only to create a few shapefiles, and then stops.
Is there a way to solve this problem? Or is it a matter of corrupted files and I should just ask for different files? I have no problems seeing the polygons in the main window...

You dont have any weird characters in the Unique ID field, right? Like asterisks?

@BERA: yes, I do, but I tried deleting them and nothing changed

I also tried operating on the files using AecGIS Pro, and there's still some errors. What's strange is that in QGIS I was able to (e.g.) create random points in different polygons, and with ArcGIS I wasn0t able to do it because "ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
"
